# Way to create an interactive dictionary for Google Docs?

Tags: software, organization, dictionary, google-docs

I'm using Google Docs to both write a story and to create a dictionary of sorts for ease of writing. I'm trying to figure out a way that I can either have a word suggestion box pop up on Google Docs with the list of words I have in my descriptive word dictionary, or I'd like to know of a note-like program where I can organize all the words in the descriptive word dictionary I've created.

The word suggestion box comes to mind because there are coding programs that suggest different words for different commands.

The interactive notes comes up because I'm used to creating folders upon folders in my computer and think that organizing the words with such a system would be very useful.

Comment: I think this is possible, but it will require programming.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this writing program attempts to help you do something very similar to what you are looking for: [Genre](http://writegenre.com/)

From its page about its features:

> Create a profile card for all your characters in a dedicated sidebar. Genre will highlight character names in your story. Mouse over a name to see that character’s profile.

It looks like you can also do something similar with the outline of your story:

> Link your outline notes to individual chapters. They will show in the top, always in reach during writing.

And you can also do that with any important term in your story:

> Highlight important terms, concepts or places in your story, just by making a note about them.

It doesn't give you typing suggestions like you mentioned, but it does a bunch of other helpful things like it.

Comment: I didn't know Genre, and I will check it out. I just add that other creative writing programs, such as the famous Scrivener, have similar features for highlighting, noting and create definition for specific words.